# Is it possible to write to the Windows Event Viewer with an OpCode through .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, event-viewer

I am trying to find out if there is any way to write into the OpCode field in the Windows Event Viewer, .NET's EventLog implementation does not seem to provide a parameter or way which lets this field be populated in any of the overridden WriteEvent or WriteEntry functions.

I have a sample project at https://github.com/calvinnorton/SampleLogApplication/ which is the most simplified version of a program I have been able to create that can demonstrate the problem.

Throughout tutorials, questions and slideshows on the web, people add OpCode attributes to their code examples but don't seem to follow through on getting it into the Event Viewer, and I have not been able to find a screenshot of someone's event that they have written utilising an OpCode.

MSDN for example specifies OpCodes in their example functions but do not show those opcodes being passed into the actual WriteEvent functions. (I don't have enough reputation to add more than 2 links and I think the other links are more useful possibly, but a google search on EventAttribute.OpCode should bring the link up)

Other questions ask about OpCodes but do not seem to try and get them into the EventViewer at all such as: [Specifying different eventID and task category values using ETW / EventSource Library for the event viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292571/specifying-different-eventid-and-task-category-values-using-etw-eventsource-li)

[image]

Looking through other logs available, it appears most applications do not report any sort of OpCode to the Event Viewer, but they're relatively prevalent throughout the logs underneath Microsoft->Windows, maybe it's possibly something Microsoft has access to but does not let us log through this system.

Comment: The logs underneath Microsoft->Windows are all ETW Channels - as opposed to "classic" EventLogs. AFAIK the classic logs don't support the OpCode field